# htmlagilitypack select all images exclude *.gif

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I parse html page

```
 HtmlNode body = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
```

from body I extract all images

```
HtmlNodeCollection allImages = body.SelectNodes("//img[@src!='']");
```

how I can exclude images with extension **".gif"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
//img[not(contains(@src,'.gif'))]
```

Or more accurately the following will ignore the `img` tags where the src attribute value ends with `.gif`

```
//img[substring(@src, string-length(@src) - string-length('.gif') +1) != '.gif']
```